# Setting value of picturebox from blob data in Telerik Reporting

Tags: c#, telerik-reporting

I wanted to convert the `BLOB` into image in order to display the pictures in report but I get this error

> An error has occurred while processing PictureBox 'pictureBox1':
> Invalid image data. - InnerException - A generic error occurred in GDI+.

The pictureBox is inside the table cell

Here is my code:

```
public Students()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
  dt1.Clear();
  dt1.Columns.Add("No");
  dt1.Columns.Add("FullName");
  dt1.Columns.Add("Address");
  dt1.Columns.Add("Img");

using (var con = new SqlConnection(connection.DB()))
        {
            var query = String.Format(@"SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.lastname, a.firstname, a.middlename) as No,
            CONCAT(a.lastname, ', ', a.firstname, ' ', a.middlename) as FullName,
            a.Address,
            a.id
            FROM masterlist.dbo.students_masterlist as a
            ORDER BY FullName");
            var com = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            con.Open();
            var reader = com.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                DataRow value = dt1.NewRow();
                value["No"] = Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(0));
                value["FullName"] = Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(1));
                value["Address"] = Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(2));
                pictureBox1.Value = LoadBlobImage(Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(3)));
                dt1.Rows.Add(value);
            }
        }
        this.table1.DataSource = dt1;
}

public Image LoadBlobImage(string id)
    {
        Image image;
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(connection.DB()))
        {
            var query = String.Format(@"SELECT TOP 1 [file] 
                FROM masterlist.dbo.students_pictures as z 
                WHERE z.id= @ID");
            var com = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            con.Open();
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
            byte[] img = (byte[])com.ExecuteScalar();
            using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(img))
            {
                image = Image.FromStream(ms);
            }
        }
        return image;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

make a user function with invisible false property. and set this function in picturebox expression and pass the base64 or binary value, which you had stored in database.